# Playing a low res WAV/PCM file using a Basic Stamp II microcontroler speaker

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, wave

Is there a way to convert PCM data to PWM impulsion so that I can send it a basic stamp microcontroler in order to play audio on a external speaker ?

(without using an IC)

Answer (score 4):

Convert your sound file to a WAV file:

```
mplayer -ao pcm music.mp3
```

Make an unsigned mono 8bit version at the desired sample rate:

```
sox audiodump.wav -c 1 -r 8000 -u -1 converted.wav
```

Convert the samples to a C header file (get [wav2c](http://thieumsweb.free.fr/english/gbacss.html)):

```
wav2c converted.wav sounddata.h sounddata
```

(For your BASIC Stamp, you'll need to convert this array into some other format).

Then, in your application you need to read one sample from the array each time the sample rate duration expires and transmit it out of your PWM pin.

Comment: jpc: You could make that comment into an answer so it can receive upvotes.

Comment: Yes I can. It still would be best represented as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To generate RAW samples from an audio file you could use mplayer

```
mplayer -af resample=48000,channels=2:2:0:1:0:0,format=s16le 
        -ao pcm:nowaveheader:file=outfile.raw
        infile.mp3
```

This outputs raw 16 bit little-endian samples to `outfile.raw`. You can then proceed like Joby suggested (just use a bin2c tool, and not wav2c).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do such procedure before (I read [Enide! - PIC sound player (PCM to PWM converter)](http://www.enide.net/webcms/index.php?page=pcm2pwm)),
but I didn't regonize the original sound.

I called the statement: PWM pin, duty, cycles,
which "converts a digital value to analog output via pulse-width modulation,
where Cycles is a variable/constant (0-65535) specifying an approximate
number of milliseconds of PWM output."

This means I can send only one sample per millisecond.
So my sample rate should be 1000 Hz.
Is it true?

I'm wondering why I didn't recognize the sound. Maybe it comes from the way I converted the WAV file on my computer.

Comment: In this case you would need to change the 48000 to 1000 in the conversion. What is the resolution of the `duty` parameter and does it depend on `cycles`? Another possible problem is that you must keep calling this PWM statement on regular intervals or you will get distortion.

Comment: duty : a value between 0 and 255 which is translated in a voltage between +0 and +5 Volt

mplayer -af resample=1000 is not accepted, according to mplayer rate must be >=8000

Comment: 1kHz is really very low bandwidth for audio. You may try to use 8kHz — I think you should be able to recognize a slowed down version of your sound. Audacity seems to support 1000 Hz sample rates (and AFAIR it can directly export to a RAW file) so you may try to generate a simple sinusoid to see if the PWM is working well.